# Transform uv layout to square

Tags: uv

UV Squares addon not working anymore on my blender 2.79 version
How i can turn selected uv layout into square without that addon?

I wanna make uv layout into square because i can't transer uv from other object as they had diffrent geometry

Comment: Maybe Quad Unwrap? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcFEdK5TQv0

Comment: Active face must be exacly 4 vertices?

Comment: Sorry I don't know this addon, I just know it's a bit like UV Squares